# Why while loop closes after I enter new char value

Tags: c#, while-loop, char

Even if I enter the y value to be 'y', loop still closes.
If I enter the value 'y', then it asks "Do you want to continue? Press y" and loop closes without asking to enter new y value.

```
char y = 'y';
while (y == 'y')
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Do you want to continue? Press y");
            y = (char)Console.Read(); //here the problem starts
         }
```

Comment: Add a breakpoint and see what the value of y is immediately after the read from console

Comment: this is working on my system (as it is) - y let's you continue

Comment: remark: in this case a `do ... while` is much more readable IMHO (you an but the `(char)Console.Read() == 'y'` right into the `while`-part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Console.Read() blocks waiting for the input and terminates by pressing the enter key which appends a carriage return which is what it will read next time through the loop.This is one example of why Read() is not the best option when you need to redirect flow based on user input,instead you have other options:

First:Consume the rest of the input buffer by placing a readline after like this:

```
char y = 'y';
while (y == 'y')
{
    char temp;
    Console.WriteLine("Do you want to continue? Press y");
    y = (char)Console.Read();
    Console.ReadLine();   
}
```

Second: Simply replace Read() for ReadLine() altering the char to a string or if you want to keep the char like this:

```
y = (char)Console.ReadLine()[0];
```

Third:Using ReadKey():

```
ConsoleKeyInfo key = Console.ReadKey();
y = key.KeyChar;
Console.WriteLine();
```

Comment: If it is not too much to ask, can you please explain what is the [0] in second example? I tried to google, but google doesn't search for square brackets.

Comment: Its the indexer into the string,for example : string str = "test"; char c = str[0]; the char c would have 't' if it was [1] c would be 'e'.